# Function parameter not allowing interface type (typescript)

Tags: typescript, interface, typescript-typings

value parameter (IUser type) in show function is also accepting other
properties like 'token' here which is not defined in IUser interface
**why is this possible**

```
interface IUser {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

const show = (value: IUser) => {
   console.log(value);
}

const user = {
  name: "adarsh",
  age: 12,
  token: "$DSJHjdh78D",
};

show(user);


/*
 *  OUTPUT
 *  { name: 'adarsh', age: 12, token: '$DSJHjdh78D' }
*/
```

This should give an error because IUser interface doesnt have token property signature

Comment: TypeScript does not prohibit extra properties except in the very specific situation where you make an object literal and immediately throw away the information of the extra property, like `const x: IUser = {name: "", age: 0, token: ""}`, since there's nowhere `token` will be remembered.  For `const x = {name: "", age: 0, token: ""}; const y: IUser = x;`, the `x` variable knows about `token`, so it's not an error.  See the answers to the linked questions for more information.